# Cesium GeoJSON datasource polygon material is white despite an image is specified

Tags: cesiumjs

I am not able to figure out a way to change the [material](https://cesium.com/docs/cesiumjs-ref-doc/Material.html) of a polygon [entity](https://cesium.com/docs/cesiumjs-ref-doc/Entity.html) from a [GeoJsonDataSource](https://cesium.com/docs/cesiumjs-ref-doc/GeoJsonDataSource.html). I would like to apply an image.

Here is an [example](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=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) using a color because I don't know how to embed an image on the online sandcastle:

```js
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer("cesiumContainer");

const poly = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "name": "MyPolygon",
    "crs": {"type": "name",
            "properties": {
                "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
    }},
    "features": [
        {"type": "Feature",
         "properties": {},
         "geometry": {
             "type": "Polygon",
             "coordinates": [
                 [[ 10.746500009923748, 48.314700009648320, 500 ],
                  [ 10.747500009924019, 48.315700009648104, 500 ],
                  [ 10.747038310965864, 48.315905422444722, 550 ],
                  [ 10.746038315853207, 48.314905418639555, 550 ],
                  [ 10.746500009923748, 48.314700009648320, 500 ]] 
]}}]};

const Promise0 = async () => {
    try {
        const dataSource = await Cesium.GeoJsonDataSource.load(poly, {
            stroke: Cesium.Color.BLUE,
            strokeWidth: 3
        });
        const Promise1 = async () => {
            try {
                const polygonalFrame = await viewer.dataSources.add(dataSource);
                viewer.zoomTo(polygonalFrame);
                const entities = polygonalFrame.entities.values;
                for (var i = 0; i < entities.length; i++) {
                    const entity = entities[i];
                    entity.polygon.material = new Cesium.Material({
                        fabric : {
                          type : 'Color',
                          uniforms : {
                            color : new Cesium.Color(1.0, 0.0, 0.4, 0.5)
                          }
                        }
                      });
                }
            }
            catch (err) {
                console.log("Error: ", err);
            }
        };
        Promise1();
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log("Error:", e);
    }
};
Promise0();
```

The polygon remains yellow, which is the default color I think.

For the image material, I use this definition locally:

```js
new Cesium.Material({
    fabric : {
        type : 'Image',
        uniforms : {
            image : './image.png'
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it using [this](https://cesium.com/docs/cesiumjs-ref-doc/ImageMaterialProperty.html) way of defining the [PolygonGraphics](https://cesium.com/docs/cesiumjs-ref-doc/PolygonGraphics.html#material)' material in my [entity](https://cesium.com/docs/cesiumjs-ref-doc/Entity.html#polygon):

```js
new Cesium.ImageMaterialProperty({
    image: './image.png',
    alpha: 0.5
});
```

But I noticed that [alpha blending](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing) doesn't work when I try to apply it on my whole image...